# Mix found values and error msg in csv - Get-ADUser search

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I would like to take a csv of e-mail addresses and find users that match those addresses. Output should be either the found user info OR if a matching user is not found a line that puts the searched for e-mail address then "Not Found"

```
$base_path = "C:\scripts\validate_users\"
$source_file = "input_emails.csv"
$out_file = "results.csv"

#read the file, look them up
$users = Import-csv -Path ($base_path + $source_file) -delimiter ";" | ForEach {

    try {
        Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.email)'" -Properties EmailAddress
        }
    catch { 
        "No user for" + '$_.email' 
        }
    }

# Output the resultant collection to a csv file
$users | Export-csv -Path ($base_path + $out_file)
```

Which gives me all the found records and no error messages.

I'd like to avoid making $users into an array and adding a value there. Is there a way to add in-line "searchedforuser@fakedomain.com NOT FOUND" inline with the results I get now.

Input is along the lines of

```
joesmith@ourdomain.com
janejones@ourdomain.com
freddielee@ourdomain.com
guywhoquit@ourdomain.com <== won't find this one
realuser@ourdomain.com
```

Right now the output is just the results for the four found users with no indication the "guywhoquit@ourdomain.com" was ever in the original list

Sorry if this is a newb question. I am a ps newb, but I searched for quite a bit and I'm missing if a similar question has already been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `Get-AdUser` with the **`-Filter` parameter**, it will simply **return `$null` if no matching user is found** (assuming the `-Filter` argument is well-formed) - it **won't report an *error***.

Therefore, **check the `Get-ADUser`'s *output*** to see if a user was found.
The **`-ov` (`-OutVariable`) common parameter allows you to capture a cmdlet's output in a variable** (independently of its output behavior), which you can inspect later:

```
$base_path = "C:\scripts\validate_users"
$source_file = "input_emails.csv"
$out_file = "results.csv"

Import-csv -Path (Join-Path $base_path $source_file) -delimiter ";" | ForEach {

  # Get and output the user for the email address at hand;
  # also store the output in variable $user, via `-ov user`    
  Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.email)'" -Properties EmailAddress -ov user

  if ($user.Count -eq 0) { # User not found?
    # Emit a dummy object with an .EmailAddress property
    # whose value indicates that the user wasn't found.
    # This will show up in the CSV file as a row with all columns
    # except the "EmailAddress" one empty.
    [pscustomobject] @{ EmailAddress = "No user for $($_.email)" }
  }

} | Export-csv -Path (Join-Path $base_path $out_file)
```

Note: The reason that just emitting *string* `"No user for" + '$_.email'` to the output stream wouldn't be enough is that `Export-Csv` *locks in the columns* it outputs *based on the 1st input object*.

A `[string]` instance has no properties in common with an AD users object, so you'd get a CSV row *without any values*.

By constructing a dummy custom object with an `.EmailAddress` property (`[pscustomobject] @{ EmailAddress = "..." }`), that property value *will* show up in the file (though all other column values will be empty).

Comment: Thanks, @BarrettBuss.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is that Powershell only catches "Terminating exceptions" to solve this you could try either of this 2 following modifications:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$($_.email)'" -Properties EmailAddress -ErrorAction Stop #This will only affect this cmdlet.
```

Or

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop' #This affects every cmdlet execution you have after this line.
```

Comment: Since `-Filter` is being used, no _errors_ (of any type) will be reported - not finding a match simply (quietly) results in no output.